# Using GA4 to track users cross domain

Tags: google-analytics

Recently I've seen couple of issues with the user data that I get from Google Analytics related to Iframe's. I have web application hosted on domain `example.com`. I get different requests based on user needs like `example.com/?id=1`. In one specific case, my webpage is in an Iframe on another domain called `iframedomain.com/example`. When I check user data on Google Analytics, the user data I get from Iframe does not match what I see in HTTP requests to that specific page.

What I wonder is whether GA4 tracks users from other domain that has my Iframe in it or not? I have found some documentation on [Cross Domain Measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) and [Linker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker) for analytics. I wonder whether there is another solution without exchanging client ID's or not?